# How to install a new TFS checkin policy on a TFS 2010 server?

Tags: team-foundation-server

We've recently upgraded our TFS server to TFS 2010 from 2008.  We've been researching a couple new add-on checkin policies we want to install.  The only problem is that all documentation I can find on adding new policies to the server appears to be specific to TFS 2008 or earlier.  Those steps involve adding new keys in the registry which do not exist on our 2010 TFS server.  Does anybody know where the process to install new checkin policies on a TFS 2010 server so they can be applied to Team Projects is documented?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check out this post it seems to cover it pretty well:

http://blogs.msdn.com/jimlamb/archive/2010/03/31/how-to-implement-package-and-deploy-custom-check-in-policy-for-tfs-2010.aspx

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668980.aspx) seems to the the best MSDN documentation.  [This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929240/deploying-custom-policy-on-tfs2010-using-vsix-and-pkgdef) helps fill in the missing bits in *Jim Lamb's blog post* mentioned earlier.

You might also find the result of searching for "Using The Custom Assembly Path to Deploy Custom TFS Checkin Policies", an MSDN blog post, useful.  I can't post more than two links, so please search for that one yourself!

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Beware JimLambs' solution does not work ASIS. I have tried using his example and  I get the following message:

"Internal error in Code Review Policy.  Error loading the Code Review Policy policy (The assembly ... is not registered.)"

similar to what one of his blog viewers have left on that blog